# Hibernate: convert cursor returned from stored procedure to List

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have implemented a code for calling stored procedure from hibernate. The sp returns a cursor, how do I get the result in List.

Below is my code for calling the sp. How to I create a list from **callstm.getObject(1);**

I'm using Oracle.

```
    Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Object>() {

            @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
            @Override
            public Object execute( Connection aConnection ) throws SQLException
            {
                CallableStatement callstm = null;
                try
                {
                    String functionCall = "{call PORTAL_PKG._pp_member_login(?, ?, ?, ? )}";
                    callstm = aConnection.prepareCall( functionCall );
                    callstm.registerOutParameter( 1, OracleTypes.CURSOR );
                    callstm.setString( 2, "Partner" );
                    callstm.setString( 3, "Member" );
                    callstm.setString( 4, "test@123" );

                    callstm.execute();

                    callstm.getObject(1);                       
                }
                finally
                {
                   callstm.close();
                }
            }

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis my actual requirement is to get the returned value from the cursor. The code is working fine, but im not sure how to get the values from  "callstm.getObject(1); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
...
callstm.execute();
ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)callstm.getObject(1);
while (rset.next()){
      System.out.println(rset.getString(columnIndex));
}
// Close all the resources
...
```